# How to retrieve key-value pairs as a generic collection with values of different types?

Tags: c#

I am working on a `C#` app where we are storing data as `key-value` pairs in sqlite. I have implemented `KeyValue` as a holder class for (key,value) pair and `ReadTransaction` as a read-only transaction class:

```
public class ReadTransaction
{
    Task<T> GetValue<T>(string key);
}

public class KeyValue<TValue>
{
    public KeyValue(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    public KeyValue(string key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Key { get; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have another method in `ReadTransaction` class that takes IEnumerable of keys and returns `IEnumerable<something>` that has the data for the keys with keys included.

I can't do this:

```
Task<IEnumerable<KeyValue<T>>> GetValues<T>(IEnumerable<string> keys);
```

because the values at these keys could be of different types.

How can I write/implement this function?

Comment: you can replace T with dynamic

Comment: @Polly. dynamic will make OP lose type safety

Comment: Can TValue be different type for each key? If so how do you expect `IEnumerable<KeyValue<T>>` would work?

Comment: If this collection stores elements of different types than it's not storing elements of type T. You could use 'object' if you really need to, but you should really think twice before storing elements of different types in a single collection.

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü TValue could be of any type for a key.

Comment: @Monku, `TValue could be of any type for a key` if that is the case then look at what `tymtam` said.

Comment: @tymtam the end data is stored in sqlite as `<key,blob(serialized value)>`. so it's not really a collection. may be I could return `IEnumerable<KeyValue<byte[]>>` because at the call site client code will know what key stores what type of value but then it means I need deserializer there.

Answer (score 1):

I would discourage you from storing elements of different types in the same collection.

If you need to then you could use 'object', as in `Dictionary<string,object>`.